# Force screen reader to read numbers as individual digits

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm using voice over and I'm trying to get it to read numbers as individual digits, for example if I have inputted 2000, voice over will read out "two thousand". I want the desired behaviour to read out "two zero zero zero".

my current input element looks something like this

```
<input class="some-class" id="some-id" name="some-name"
 type="text">
```

I have tried setting the type attribute to `type="number"`, `type="tel"` and adding a style attribute equal to `style="speak:spell-out"`, but non of them worked.

When I separate the numbers with whitespace like `value="2 0 0 0"` it works, but of course, you can't expect the user to do this.

I understand there may be a way to do this using javascript, but the solution can not contain javascript in the browser due to business requirements.

Any suggestions?

Comment: onchange="this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/, '').split('').join(' ')"

Comment: @QuentinC is correct, do not attempt to do this, unless you can give a very specific reason why you think you should try and alter output you should just let screen readers do their thing, screen reader users can use controls to read one character at a time if they need to.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't try to force a particular pronunciation or digit grouping.
Add spaces if grouping has a particular importance or meaning.

Take the base principle that numbers shouldn't be read differently by a screen reader than it is presented.
If digits must be separated in a particular way, add spaces, dots, dashes or another separation character.
Conversely, if there's no spaces, there's no special need to absolutely read a number digit by digit.
That's quite simple.

You shouldn't force the screen reader to read something in the way you view it yourself.
Other people may not have the same vision as you. Concerning numbers, some people will prefer to read digit by digit, but others will prefer having them grouped by two, three or four, for their ease of reading, writing and memorizing. Their screen reader is normally configured accordingly.

If a given grouping is important, then groups must be separated with spaces or other characters. If there's no separations, then it implicitly means that grouping has no particular importance.

Note that screen readers always give the possibility to read numbers digit by digit, if the user wish to do so. It is usually not the default.
Reading numbers digit by digit is usually done only for very big numbers (billions), or when mixing digits and letters.

Additionally consider that:

- Different screen reader users have different preferences, and accessibility speaking, it's generally a bad idea  to go against  preferences or common defaults
- There are several screen readers, and a lot of different voices in many languages; all potentially behave in slightly different way when reading numbers, and any small change in order to tweak it might create more problems than solve.
- Screen reader users are used to pronunciation quirks, and they can fix them using personal dictionary
- Screen readers are nowadays not that bad on deciding whether they need to read numbers at a hole, in groups, or digit by digit.

So, avoid deciding a particular grouping or pronunciation. It's a bad idea, and anyway technically perilous.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I should clarify, the number that is being read is going to be 8 numbers long (10 millions).

I understand what your saying and it makes sense, but I need to have the number read out digit by digit in this case. Do have any ideas to make this work?

Comment: Tehre is no way to ensure that your number will be read digit by digit, other than adding spaces anyway. I'm a screen reader user myself. If I really need to read a number digit by digit, I always have this possibility, but by default I don't need to. You really shouldn't impose me your way of reading your number, it may not be mine. I'll update my answer a bit.

Comment: Perhaps you can give more context why you really need to read the number digit by digit? Is it an account number? a phone number? A PIN? None of the three have that absolute need imo. Is it rather financial? scientific? IN this case seriously consider spacing/grouping.

Comment: @QuentinC I have a quite different issue but Google sended me here... I have a select with the values `10 - 20`, `21 - 50` and so on. But the screen reader either says `ten twenty` or via `10-20`  (`one zero two zero`). Is there a way to make it spell `ten to twenty` or something? I know you said we should not force a screen reader to spell something in a different way but do screen readers understand the difference between `10 - 20`  (`ten twenty`)  (`10 20`) -> `ten twenty`

Comment: Unless you explicitly write "10 to 20", no, but don't worry. The context should make it clear enough that you are selecting a range.
You may use aria-label, but 1/it won't work in `<option>`, and 2/it's probably totally useless for your case.
If you want more precisions, don't hesitate to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand there may be a way to do this using javascript, but the solution can not contain javascript in the browser due to business requirements.

You tried HTML and CSS and you can't use Javascript. Screenreaders use the Accessibility tree. They do not use CSS, there's no instruction to tell them to spell the text. They might choose to spell some abbreviations while reading some acronym. This is screenreader choice.

Screenreader users are used to ear numbers as strangely as they come and if they want them to be read char by char they have the appropriate shortcut to willingly spell them.